# Несколько директорий makefile(src и inc)

Tags: gcc, makefile

Привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать сборку проекта из нескольких папок. в src - исходники(.c), а в inc - хидеры(.h).
Я хотел бы реализовать сборку через makefile и linux машину. Если не сложно дайте пожалуйста пример makefile.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в основном каталоге (где находятся папки src include) такой Makefile

```
all:
    #ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q .
    cd src ; make  all
clean:
    cd src ; make clean
install:
    cd src ; make install
```

закомментированная строка - это для vim'a, что бы он мог собрать файл тегов.

а этот файл - в каталоге `src`:

```
###
# EDITABLE SECTION start
###

##########
#MODE=DEBUG
MODE=RELEASE

##########################################
# определим define, который определит текущую дату. полезно
BUILDDATE := $(shell date +%d%m%Y)

# выбираем разные настройки в зависимости от типа сборки - релиз/дебаг
ifeq ($(MODE),DEBUG)
OPTFLAGS=-g3  -ggdb 
DEFINES=-DDEBUG -DBUILDDATE=\"$(BUILDDATE)\" 
else
OPTFLAGS=-O1 -ggdb -DNDEBUG
DEFINES=-DBUILDDATE=\"$(BUILDDATE)\"
endif

# а здесь то, что будет включено во все типы сборок
# Define always
DEFINES+=-D_REENTRANT -D_PTHREADS -D__USE_GNU

#  вот здесь ключевой момент - включается каталог include. Все инклуды в сорцах должны включаться оносительно каталога include
INCLUDES= -I../include -I/usr/local/mylib
LIBPATH = -L/usr/local/mylyb 
# параметры линковщика. проверьте
LINK=сс -m32 -Wl,-L/usr/lib32,-melf_i386

# компилятор
CFLAGS = $(OPTFLAGS) -Wall -pedantic  $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -m32 -pipe
СС=gсс

# а это каталог, где будет бинарник
BINDIR=../bin

###
# EDITABLE SECTION end
###

# здесь нужно вставить полный список всех c/cpp файлов
SRC=    list_of_your_c_files

# это такой трюк, что бы получить имена .о файлов.
OBJS=$(subst .c,.o,$(SRC))

all:    $(OBJS)  main_task

main_task:
    $(LINK) $(LIBPATH) $(LIBS) -o $(BINDIR)/binary_name $(OBJS)

# это правило преобразования c -> .o
$(OBJS):    %.o: %.c
    $(СС) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.so
    rm -f *~
    rm -f ../include/*~
```

я его переделывал с своего плюсового проекта, поэтому мог ошибиться в параметрах компилятора или линковщика.

P.S. и не забывайте об отступах в файле, make очень придирчив.